# How to update IntVar after typing in Entry widget?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I would like to make a balance entry widget, which will accept only integers, and value must be 20 - 5000. I have made only int criteria, but i have no idea how to handle with 20 - 5000 value limits.

I tried to make a "Start game button" which execute if statement, but it does not update the value which i typed in entry box, it has 0 by default at the beginning, even if its it command function of a button.

If someone knows a solution please give me a hint!

@EDIT: Whole my code below!

```
# Import modules
import tkinter as tk


class MainApplication(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.window_geom = WindowsProperties(self.master)
        self.master.withdraw()

    # Opening first window as a Toplevel
    def new_window(self):
        self.first_window = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
        self.app = FirstWindow(self.first_window)

class FirstWindow(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)

        # Create all root objects:
        self.window_geom = WindowsProperties(self.master)
        self.root_buttons = FirstWindowButtons(self.master)
        self.root_entry = FirstWindowEntry(self.master)
        self.root_labels = FirstWindowLabels(self.master)

class FirstWindowEntry(tk.Frame):
    # Class contain every button on a first screen, with its functions.
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)

        self.player_name = tk.StringVar()
        self.vcmd1 = self.register(self.callback_name)
        self.player_name_entry = tk.Entry(
            master,
            textvariable=self.player_name,
            font=("Verdana", 12),
            width=15,
            validate="all",
            validatecommand=(self.vcmd1, "%P"),
        )
        self.player_name_entry.place(x=700, y=230)
        self.player_name_entry.focus()

        self.player_balance = tk.IntVar()
        self.vcmd2 = self.register(self.callback_balance)
        self.player_balance_entry = tk.Entry(
            master,
            textvariable=self.player_balance,
            font=("Verdana", 12),
            width=15,
            validate="all",
            validatecommand=(self.vcmd2, "%P"),
        )
        self.player_balance_entry.place(x=700, y=270)

    # Method which validate if entered str is digit in Balance Entry
    def callback_balance(self, P):
        if len(P) <= 5 and (str.isdigit(P) or P == ""):
            return True
        else:
            return False

    # Method which validate if entered str is not longer than 15 characters in Player name Entry
    def callback_name(self, P):
        if len(P) <= 15:
            return True
        else:
            return False


class FirstWindowButtons(FirstWindowEntry):
    # Class contain every button on a first screen, with its functions.
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)

        self.start_button = tk.Button(master, command=self.start_button_func)
        self.start_button_img = tk.PhotoImage(
            file="C:/Users/rjg5by/Scripts/venv/blackjack/start_button_img.png"
        )
        self.start_button.config(
            image=self.start_button_img,
            borderwidth=-10,
            bg="black",
            activebackground="black",
        )
        self.start_button.place(x=630, y=500)

        self.quit_button = tk.Button(master, command=self.quit_button_func)
        self.quit_button_img = tk.PhotoImage(
            file="C:/Users/rjg5by/Scripts/venv/blackjack/quit_button_img.png"
        )

        self.quit_button.config(
            image=self.quit_button_img,
            borderwidth=-10,
            bg="black",
            activebackground="black",
        )
        self.quit_button.place(x=800, y=500)

    def start_button_func(self):
        print(self.player_balance.get())
        if self.player_balance.get() >= 20:
            root.deiconify()  # Main game play windows appears
            self.master.destroy()  # Exit of first window
        else:
            print("Not enough ")

    def quit_button_func(self):
        root.destroy()


class FirstWindowLabels(tk.Frame):
    # Class contain every button on a root screen, with its functions.
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)

        self.player_name_label = tk.Label(
            master, text="Player name:", font=("Verdana", 14)
        )
        self.player_name_label.config(fg="white", bg="black")
        self.player_name_label.place(x=540, y=230)

        self.player_balance_label = tk.Label(
            master, text="Balance:", font=("Verdana", 14)
        )
        self.player_balance_label.config(fg="white", bg="black")
        self.player_balance_label.place(x=540, y=270)


class WindowsProperties(tk.Frame):
    # Class define windows main properties.
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)

        self.width_of_window = 980
        self.height_of_window = 604
        self.screen_width = self.master.winfo_screenwidth()
        self.screen_height = self.master.winfo_screenheight()
        self.x_coordinate = int((self.screen_width / 2) - (self.width_of_window / 2))
        self.y_coordinate = int(
            (self.screen_height / 2) - (self.height_of_window / 2) - 30
        )
        self.master.geometry(
            f"{self.width_of_window}x{self.height_of_window}+{self.x_coordinate}+{self.y_coordinate}"
        )

        self.master.resizable(width=False, height=False)  # Resizable of a window

        self.master.title("Blackjack")  # Title of an application


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = MainApplication(root)
    MainApplication.new_window(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Second EDIT:

@Mike - SMT many thanks for a help! I revised my code with your instructions, I noticed that i need to put self. to image variables to make it works. After all of the corrections code looks like below, i have a question regarding gaining window properties from MainApplication Class, i put there method 'window_properties()' and run it also at TopLevel window but it does not get its properties, do you maybe have some idea how i can get it without placing the same code at toplevel wind? (without method it also not getting proper size of it)

Also, please tell me how i can get 'self.player_name' and 'self.player_balance' values in MainApp Class now?

Solution:
I have changed this lines FirstWindow() into self.first_window = FirstWindow()

and now i can get to this values by `self.first_window.player_balance` and now it works.

EDIT: I reduced not necessary code.

```
import tkinter as tk

class MainApplication(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.window_properties()
        self.withdraw()
        self.new_window()

    def new_window(self):
        FirstWindow()

    def window_properties(self):
        width_of_window = 980
        height_of_window = 604
        screen_width = self.winfo_screenwidth()
        screen_height = self.winfo_screenheight()
        x_coordinate = int((screen_width / 2) - (width_of_window / 2))
        y_coordinate = int((screen_height / 2) - (height_of_window / 2) - 30)
        self.geometry(
            f"{width_of_window}x{height_of_window}+{x_coordinate}+{y_coordinate}"
        )

class FirstWindow(tk.Toplevel):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Defining variables
        self.player_name = tk.StringVar()
        self.player_balance = tk.IntVar()

        self.master.window_properties()

        self.vcmd1 = self.register(self.callback_name)
        player_name_entry = tk.Entry(
            self,
            textvariable=self.player_name,
            font=("Verdana", 12),
            width=15,
            validate="all",
            validatecommand=(self.vcmd1, "%P"),
        )
        player_name_entry.place(x=700, y=230)
        player_name_entry.focus()

        self.vcmd2 = self.register(self.callback_balance)
        player_balance_entry = tk.Entry(
            self,
            textvariable=self.player_balance,
            font=("Verdana", 12),
            width=15,
            validate="all",
            validatecommand=(self.vcmd2, "%P"),
        )
        player_balance_entry.place(x=700, y=270)


        # Player balance Label widget
        player_balance_label = tk.Label(self, text="Balance:", font=("Verdana", 14))
        player_balance_label.config(fg="white", bg="black")
        player_balance_label.place(x=540, y=270)

        # Information about min/max balance Label widget
        self.min_max_label = tk.Label(
            self,
            text="The balance should be between 20 and 5000 $.",
            font=("Verdana", 10),
        )
        self.min_max_label.config(fg="white", bg="black")
        self.min_max_label.place(x=540, y=310)


        start_button = tk.Button(self, command=self.start_button_func)
        start_button.config(
            borderwidth=-10,
            bg="black",
            activebackground="black",
        )
        start_button.place(x=630, y=500)

        quit_button = tk.Button(self, command=self.quit_button_func)
        quit_button.config(borderwidth=-10, bg="black", activebackground="black"
        )
        quit_button.place(x=800, y=500)

    # Method which validate if entered str is digit in Balance Entry
    def callback_balance(self, P):
        if len(P) <= 5 and (str.isdigit(P) or P == ""):
            return True
        else:
            return False

    # Method which validate if entered str is not longer than 15 characters in Player name Entry
    def callback_name(self, P):
        if len(P) <= 15:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    # This method checks if player typed a name, than checks if balance is 20-5000. If all statement are ok, move to main play game window
    def start_button_func(self):
        if self.player_name.get() == "":
            self.min_max_label.config(
                fg="red", bg="black", text="Please type your name."
            )
        elif self.player_balance.get() < 20:
            self.min_max_label.config(
                fg="red",
                bg="black",
                text="Please correct your balance value. It should be at least 20 $.",
            )
        elif self.player_balance.get() > 5000:
            self.min_max_label.config(
                fg="red",
                bg="black",
                text="Please correct your balance value. Maximum is 5000 $.",
            )
        else:
            self.master.deiconify()  # Main game play windows appears
            self.destroy()  # Exit of first window

    # Quiting whole game button
    def quit_button_func(self):
        self.master.destroy()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApplication().mainloop()
```

Comment: Why do you think the variable isn't being updated? When I add enough code to run your code and see the variable, it appears to be updating. Please provide a _complete_ [mcve].

Comment: ***`start_button_func`***: [Edit] your question and show how do you call this function.

Comment: This `print(player_balance.get())` should read `print(self.player_balance.get())`.

Comment: We do not need the whole code. A well written question should include a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing here is overkill. By separating everything into different classes you are making it harder to get to variables in different classes. though possible I would build your top window all in one class instead of many.

That said I would also build your main application to inherit from Tk() instead of Frame().

I have removed your images for testing functionality of the below example.

Consider the below reworked code and let me know if you have any questions:

```
import tkinter as tk


class MainApplication(tk.Tk):
    """Main class of Blackjack Game.
    Importing game play classes and window properties
    """
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("Blackjack")
        width_of_window = 980
        height_of_window = 604
        screen_width = self.winfo_screenwidth()
        screen_height = self.winfo_screenheight()
        x_coordinate = int((screen_width / 2) - (width_of_window / 2))
        y_coordinate = int((screen_height / 2) - (height_of_window / 2) - 30)
        self.geometry(f"{width_of_window}x{height_of_window}+{x_coordinate}+{y_coordinate}")
        self.resizable(width=False, height=False)
        tk.Label(self, text='bg image').place(x=0, y=0)
        self.withdraw()
        self.new_window()

    def new_window(self):
        FirstWindow()


class FirstWindow(tk.Toplevel):
    """First window class.
    Contains player name and balance entry, label. Start/Quit buttons
    """
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.player_name = tk.StringVar()
        self.player_balance = tk.IntVar()
        tk.Label(self,  text='bg image').place(x=0, y=0)
        self.vcmd1 = self.register(self.callback_name)
        player_name_entry = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.player_name, font=("Verdana", 12),
                                     width=15, validate="all", validatecommand=(self.vcmd1, "%P"))
        player_name_entry.place(x=700, y=230)
        player_name_entry.focus()
        self.vcmd2 = self.register(self.callback_balance)
        tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.player_balance, font=("Verdana", 12), width=15, validate="all",
                 validatecommand=(self.vcmd2, "%P")).place(x=700, y=270)

        tk.Button(self, command=self.start_button_func,  text='start btn').place(x=630, y=500)

        tk.Button(self, command=self.quit_button_func, text='quit btn').place(x=800, y=500)
        tk.Label(self, text="Player name:", font=("Verdana", 14)).place(x=540, y=230)
        tk.Label(self, text="Balance:", font=("Verdana", 14)).place(x=540, y=270)

    def callback_balance(self, p):
        if len(p) <= 5 and (str.isdigit(p) or p == ""):
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def callback_name(self, p):
        if len(p) <= 15:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def start_button_func(self):
        print(self.player_balance.get())
        if self.player_balance.get() >= 20:
            self.master.deiconify()
            self.destroy()
        else:
            print("Not enough ")

    def quit_button_func(self):
        self.destroy()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApplication().mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to my problem. The thing is i was creating object in a wrong order. I made a buttons object (which define if balance is ok or not) and than an entry object, which was not correct!

Proper piece of code should look like:

```
self.window_geom = WindowsProperties(self.master)
self.root_entry = FirstWindowEntry(self.master)   # <-- Create before buttons!
self.root_buttons = FirstWindowButtons(self.master)
self.root_labels = FirstWindowLabels(self.master)
```

Comment: The order of creating of widgets has nothing to do with how entry is updating the variable.

Comment: I think it was a reason because i inherited values from entry class. If not, why after that change it works? Maybe give me your idea about that?

Comment: I see what you are doing. Why did you chose to inherit from entry class instead of just inheriting from Frame like all the other classes? Really I think they way you are doing this is overkill and is causing unnecessary work.

Comment: Mike for your information im still totally beginner. I inherited it because i needed self.player_balance.get() value, it is a different class, thus i think it is necessary to make inheritance. Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: No it would not be necessary. You can reference the variable through self.master. That said I would write all of your first window classes into one class to avoid this.